# How to base-64 encode a hex string

Tags: java, hex, base64

I am trying to base-64 encode a hex string (copied below) but the values that I get from the Java8 call to encode to base64 do not match what I am getting on different online converters.  I am trying to figure out what steps I am missing (or missteps I am taking):

```
//hexString is 07050600030102
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hexString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

//output I am getting from Java8 ic copied below:
MDcwNTA2MDAwMzAxMDI=

//online converters:
BwUGAAMBAg==
```

Comment: It's encoding the character data (not the numeric value) as base64. If you want the hex value, you need to parse it as a number first.

Comment: Most like you need to decode the hexidecimal and encode what you get decoded rather than encode it as base64 as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't do what you expect it to:

```
hexString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

That's just encoding the hex string as UTF-8 - you want to *parse* the hex string, so that each pair of hex digits ends up as a single byte. The fact that the base64 result is different is just because the bytes you're base64-encoding are different.

To parse a hex string into bytes, you can use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) (amongst other libraries)

```
byte[] bytes = BaseEncoding.base16().decode(hexString);
String base64 = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(bytes);
```

Comment: if you're using `BaseEncoding` in one direction, you might as well use it in both: `BaseEncoding.base64().encode(BaseEncoding.base16().decode(hexString))`.

Comment: thank you Jon  -I will accept shortly.  Thank you to everyone else who commented - much appreciated

Comment: @JonSkeet if I am converting a regular string (and not a hex) to base64, which call would I use with guava?  BaseEncoding.base64().decode() or else

Comment: @alihaider: Well the input to base64 encoding is *binary* data, not text... so it's really about how you want to convert text to binary data. There are multiple ways of doing that.

Answer (score 4):

Jon's answer is correct, but I thought I would make an attempt to explain it a little differently. I reckon that encoding/decoding can be a little confusing at times.

When you say that your data is encoded as a "hex string", that data is made "pretty printable". In fact, "hex encoding" is the easiest thing you can do to any binary data if you were to print it. With hex encoding, no binary data is non-printable (on computer systems that we know of)!

To make it clearer, let's say someone gives you a "hex encoded" string `a9` (the idea is same as your `07050600030102`). This means that when interpreted a certain byte stream as hex characters it becomes `a9`. Since each of the hex characters: `[0-9][a-f]` can be encoded as a nibble `0000` through `1111`, you can decode the actual bits as: `1010 1001` (blank is used for brevity). So, what is hex encoded as `a9` is in fact a single byte `10101001`.

So, if you were to now "base64-encode" it, you should use `10101001` as the input! In terms of byte array this would be: `{-87}` because `-87` is the decimal value of the bit sequence `10101001` in two's complement representation of integer values in Java.

When you do: `hexString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or `hexString.getBytes()` (if the default charset is `UTF-8` on your computer), then you are going to get the bytes of the `hexString` interpreted according to the `UTF-8` encoding and since that encoding is backward compatible with the ASCII encoding, what you'd get is a 2-byte array, the first byte of which is decimal `97` (or binary `01100001`) representing the character `'a'`, and the second byte is decimal `57`, (or binary `00111001`) representing the character `'9'` (the decimal 9). Thus, the byte array you would get from the `getBytes()` call is: `{97, 57}`.

As you can see, these two are two different things. You want to base64-encode bytes represented by array `{-87}`, but you end up base64-encoding bytes represented by array `{97, 57}`.